# Prove existence of Borel set related to the function $f(x)=2x \mod 1$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $I=[0,1)$ and $f(x)=2x \mod 1$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $E\subset I$ Borel set s.a $m(I/E)<\epsilon$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup \left\{|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} 1_{[0,1/2)}(f^j(x))-1/2|:x\in E\right\}=0$.

$f^j$ means $f\circ f\circ f\circ ...$, and $1_{[0,1/2)}(f^j(x))$ is $1$ if $f^j(x)\in [0,1/2)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Could you help me with this question?
1. this is homework. thought it would be fair to mention it. I did spend a lot of time on it though.

2. My thoughts are that given a $j$, in order for $f^j(x)$ to be $1$, $x$ has to lie in one of $j$ subsets of $[0,1/2)$ of length $1/j$ (am i right? did i understand $f$ correctly?)
3. Also, one could show that $\lim \int =0$ and therefore deduce that the integrand is $0$ a.e.
4. Lebesgue sets are the complement of the Borel sigma algebra, so if i could find any measurable set satisfies it, I could also find a Borel subset of it close enough to it.

Thanks!

P.s
I understand that it has something to do with ergodic theory. I'm not allowed to use any ergodic theorems - purely measure theory.

P.s2:
I am allowed to use this, if you should find it useful:

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, and $f_k:M\to\mathbb R$ function series. assume $\int f_k^2 <A$ and $\langle f_i,f_j\rangle=0$ for $i\not=j$. Then $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f_k(x)=0 $ a.e.

Comment: Hint: If $x$ has the binary expansion $x = 0.x_1 x_2 x_3 \dots$ then $f(x) = 0.x_2 x_3 x_4\dots$ Consider now the set of points whose binary expansions eventually become $01010101\dots$ This set doesn't quite work for $E$, but I think it's the right sort of thing to be thinking about.

Comment: @mollyerin: this set is absolutely not of full measure (it's countable!).

Comment: @D.Thomine: Of course you're right; I wasn't quite thinking straight. I'm no longer convinced my comment is helpful at all! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a few hints. The idea is first to prove:

> $$\lim_{N \to + \infty} \left| \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} 1_{[0,1/2)} \circ f^j-\frac{1}{2} \right| = 0 \ \ a.e. \ \ (*)$$

There are two ways. The first is to turn almost every $x$ into its binary expansion $0.x_0 x_1 \ldots$. Then, $x$ is chosen under the Lebesgue measure if and only if the $x_j$'s are independent and equidistributed, with $\mathbb{P} (x_j = 0) = \mathbb{P} (x_j = 0) = 1/2$. In addition, $1_{[0, 1/2)} (f^j (x)) = x_j$. The result follows from the strong law of large numbers.

But, to stay in the spirit of your question, I'd suggest to tweak the formulation. For $j \geq 0$, let $f_j := (1_{[0, 1/2)} -1/2)\circ f^j$.

**Question 1:** Prove that $f$ preserve the Lebesgue measure, i.e. that for all $\varphi \in \mathbb{L}^1 ([0,1))$, we have $\int \varphi \circ f (x) \ dx = \int \varphi (x) \ dx$. Compute $\int f_j^2 (x) \ dx$.

That's not as hard as it sounds. There are two ways. The first is to use the change of variable formula, but it needs some tweaking as $f$ is not bijective. The other is to prove the equality when $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of an interval.

Let $[a,b) \subset [0,1)$. Then what is $f^{-1} ([a,b))$? Prove that $Leb(|a,b)) = Leb(f^{-1} ([a,b)))$.

This gives you $\int \varphi \circ f (x) \ dx = \int \varphi (x) \ dx$ for $\varphi = 1_I$ for any interval $I$. Conclude.

**Question 2:** For $j \geq 0$, write carefully the set $A_j$ such that $f_j = 1_{A_j} -1/2$. Hint: $A_j = f^{-j} ([0, 1/2))$, and in your 2) you did not understand $f^j$ correctly (there are much more pieces!). You may try to draw $A_1$ and $A_2$.

The main difficulty is to see what happens and write down an explicit formula for $A_j$.

**Question 3:** For $i \neq j$, compute $\int f_i (x) f_j (x) \ dx$. Conclude.

We want to show that $\int f_i (x) f_j (x) \ dx = 0$ for $i<j$. By the preservation of measure, it is equal to $\int f_0 (x) f_{j-i} (x) \ dx = 0$. Prove that this is equivalent to $\int 1_{A_0} (x) 1_{A_{j-i}} (x) \ dx = 1/4$, that is, $Leb(A_0 \cap A_{i-j}) = 1/4$. Use the explicit formula for $A_{i-j}$ you found before.

---

Now, you have proved $(*)$. But you are not finished yet! Let $D$ be the set on which the equality of $(*)$ holds.

**Question 4:** Let $A_{N, M} := \{\sup_{n \geq N} \left| \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} 1_{[0,1/2)} \circ f^j-1/2 \right| \leq 1/M \}$. Express $D$ with the $A_{N, M}$. Show that $\bigcup_N A_{N,M}$ has full measure for all $M$.

A point is in $D$ if for all $M$, there exists $N$ such that it is in $A_{N,M}$. You should find $D = \bigcap_M \bigcup_N A_{N,M}$. Hence, $D \subset 
\bigcup_N A_{N,M}$ for all $M$.

**Question 5:** Carefully construct/choose $(N(M))_{M \geq 1}$ such that $A_{N(M), M}$ has measure at least $1-\varepsilon$. Conclude.

Let $(\varepsilon_M)_{M \geq 1} \in (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}_+}$. Show that for all $N$, you can find $N(M)$ such that $Leb(\bigcup_{N\leq N(M)} A_{N,M}) \geq (1-\varepsilon_M)$. Let $E :=\bigcap_M \bigcup_{N\leq N(M)} A_{N,M}$. Prove that $Leb (E) \geq 1-\sum_M \varepsilon_M$. Choose $(\varepsilon_M)_{M \geq 1}$ wisely.

Finally, let $M(N) := \sup \{M \geq 1: \ N(M) \leq N\}$. Prove that $\lim_{N \to + \infty} M(N) = + \infty$, and that:

$$\sup \left| \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} 1_{[0,1/2)} \circ f^j-\frac{1}{2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{M(N)} \ \ \text{on} \ E.$$

Comment: Thanks! this does seem very very complicated though, and some of the questions you gave are pretty hard to do (for example, 1). How did you come up with the idea of using this $f_j$?

Comment: And just to make myself clear - if you or anyone else could provide some more details about the intuition of your solution, and some tips about how to actually calculate the things you suggested (I don't know how to work with this $f$) it would be great

Comment: @Onel Astime: I've given much more detailed explications. As for the intuition... I'm used to working with these things; the definition of $f_j$ is usual in this context. It is not that hard when you have the apparatus of ergodic theory (Birkhoff theorem, etc.). Here, I've had to add a lot of details to re-prove some results $(*)$ which are obvious once you have this machinery. But make no mistake: this question is hard and long, and it surprises me that it is given without more detailes sub-questions or without the help of e.g. Birkhoff's theorem.